# Objective-C NSString Category Getter/Setter Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, objective-c-category

I'm trying to create NSString Category but the app crashes when trying to access getters/setters.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

@interface NSString (MyCat)

@property (assign, nonatomic) ABRecordRef personRef;

- (void)setPersonRef:(ABRecordRef)personRef;
- (ABRecordRef)personRef;

@end
```

Can anyone point out the problem?

Comment: Don't thank me for your code crashing, I didn't cause that.

Comment: Do you have an error message to with the crash?

Comment: Nope, merely EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Did you implement the getter and setter? If yes, how? Note that you cannot add instance variables to a class in a category.

Comment: Most likely the problem is (lack of) memory management with the ABRecordRef.

Comment: no need to declare the setter/getter in your `@interface`--those are implied by the presence of `@property`. You should show your setter/getter code.

Comment: Can you include an example of the usage of this property and the implementation of your getter/setter?

Comment: You need to make sure that the ownership of ABRecordRef (which is a CFTypeRef) is properly handled. Overall this is a rather tedious task when dealing with categories as you will possibly be forced to store them using associated objects (runtime level). When in doubt, I would recommend rethinking your plan to wrap this kind of data using a category on NSString.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add properties to a class via a category. Adding methods is allowed because it doesn't increase the size of the class. Properties don't just add a getter and setter method, they also add a field to your class. The best way to add properties/fields to an existing class is to subclass it.

Comment: Properties are really just a promise to supply certain accessor methods. A property doesn't necessary imply the presence of an instance variable. AFAIK, it's quite possible to add properties in a category.

Comment: @Caleb nope, properties also add storage for the property to the class, otherwise where would the auto-generated setter/getter store the data you are setting getting?

Comment: Caleb actually, you are right in a sense, however at some point you do have to set up a backing field for the property. Most of the time the compiler automatically calls @sythesize for you. However this will not work in this case as NSString has already been compiled into the SDK.

Comment: I just set up a little command line project to verify this. Attempting to set a property added by a category causes a crash.

Comment: That's because you didn't implement them in the category (you probably didn't implement the category), not because you can't add properties in categories. Apple added [objc_setAssociatedObject()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject) and friends in iOS 3.1 to support adding properties in categories.

Comment: @Lance There's a complete discussion in [Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html). It's true that you can't *just* add a property declaration and expect the compiler to fill in the blanks, but it doesn't follow that you can't use properties at all.

Comment: @Caleb and tc, I stand corrected! I learned something new today. Thanks :) However, this is probably what the asker is trying to do. _just_ add the properties. That's all we can infer from the code he provided.